# How do set environment variable in gradle via task?

Tags: java, encoding, groovy, gradle, environment-variables

I have gradle application. And my main gradle-file include some tasks (groovy).
I need when start a my task - environment variable "LANG" set encoding = ru_RU.koi8-r (for windows, linux), and after the completion of the my task - environment variable contains the initial value (en_US.UTF-8).
How do it? Help me, please.

Comment: Could you show a simple example of what you have, and what the issue is?

Comment: I think your only solution is to `System.setenv()` here.

Comment: I write:
task myTask {
    String environment = System.getenv("LANG")
    println "environment = " + environment
    System.setenv("ru_RU.koi8-r") // class System have not method 'setenv'
} But class System have not method 'setenv'!

Comment: No signature of method: static java.lang.System.setenv() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [ru_RU.koi8-r]
  Possible solutions: getenv(java.lang.String), getenv(), setIn(java.io.InputStream), setErr(java.io.PrintStream), setOut(java.io.PrintStream), getAt(java.lang.String)

Comment: I don't believe you can set System environment variables at runtime

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to have a task set an environment variable for the Gradle process. You can set environment variables when forking a new process using an `Exec` or `JavaExec` task. See the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html) for details.

Answer (score 13):

As far as I know, you cannot set system environment variable from Gradle Task.

However it is possible to set environment variable for that process. Thus if you need to set environment variable just for the build use this:

```
task MyTask(type: Exec) {
  environment 'ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_NAME', 'environment_variable_value'

  // run or build code that needs that environment variable
}
```

You can also make compile depend on that task so if you build your code you set environment variable before you compile:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
  compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn MyTask
}
```

Comment: I keep getting an error: `Could not find method environment() for arguments [MY_KEY, myvalue]`

Comment: This only works with (type: Exec) or in the test {} closure

Answer (score 12):

I had to do some research in this topic and will try to clarify some open issues. I would do that in two comments instead, but I do not have enough reputation yet. Since I found Igor Ganapolsky's comment also on other Websites but without an answer everytime I feel the need to write another answer here even if the question actually is already answered.

As Martin Rajniak stated you can set an environment variable like he showed. But that variable is only valid for the task it is defined in or the corresponding process respectively. That means you cannot use it in another following task. I verified that by defining two depending tasks like so:

```
task('firstTask', type:Exec) {
    environment "FOO", "bar"

    workingDir '.'
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'print.bat'
}

task ('secondTask', type:Exec) {
    dependsOn firstTask

    workingDir '.'
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'print.bat'
}
```

The command `print.bat` does only echo the environment variable:

```
@echo off
echo %FOO%
```

Running the build using the command `gradle secondTask` will yield:

```
> Task :firstTask
bar

> Task :secondTask
ECHO ist ausgeschaltet (OFF).
```

So the environment variable is not there anymore for `secondTask`.

So much for the actual topic, but there is another important thing, which may be the cause for Igor's problem:
The method `environment` is not available for every Gradle task. As you can see in the documentation of the [`Exec`-task-type](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html) the method `environment` is explicitly defined for the `Exec`-task-type.

To be complete I want to mention that you can pass variables to a java process by using the [`JavaExec`-task-type](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/JavaExec.html) and its method `systemProperty`. But you can not use `environment` here, because that method is not defined for the `JavaExec`-task-type.

However, I myself am still looking for a way to define an environment variable that is valid for the whole build without defining it directly via the operating system.

Comment: Hi, have you got the answer of this?
Please share i have to set env var in idea task.

Comment: Sorry no, I did not dive deeper regarding this topic.

Answer (score 7):

Combining with [Gradle Environment variables. Load from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50509084/gradle-environment-variables-load-from-file)
question, for Java plugin it would be..

```
tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    file('.env').readLines().each() {
        def (key, value) = it.tokenize('=')
        environment key, value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier solution

```
tasks.withType(org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test) {
    systemProperty 'host', 'DEV'
}
```

Comment: The question is about env property. This works for me, but it makes sense to mention it in your answer, that it does not put anything in environment, but rather in the system property.

Comment: Did not work, I had to use `environment` instead of `systemProperty`

Answer (score 0):

To set an environment variable for a particular task type, you can use the following code snippet. The environment variable "DOCKER_HOST" would be set to all tasks of the type "Exec".

```
tasks.withType(Exec) {
    environment "DOCKER_HOST", "tcp://localhost:2375"
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work at project level and for Default Task type.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [the Gradle Wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html); commit the new files (`gradlew.sh` & `gradlew.bat`) after calling `gradle wrapper` in the project root folder, then edit them as follows:

1. In `gradlew.sh` and add:
   e.g. `export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=1536`
   before:
   `exec "$JAVACMD" "$@"`
2. In `gradlew.bat` and add:
   e.g. `set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=1536` 
   (or something like that).
   before:
   `@rem Execute Gradle
   "%JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% %JAVA_OPTS% %GRADLE_OPTS% "-Dorg.gradle.appname=%APP_BASE_NAME%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain %CMD_LINE_ARGS%`
3. Modify any scripts, jenkins/travis files and IDE that calls `gradle` to `gradlew`
4. Commit so no one has to feel the grief again.

Some may consider this dirty, others an ok hack - either way it does work and allows me to go to the next problem ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I have a possible work around

If you have a something like in  *build.gradle*
(generating java class from avro schema for a file)

```
    task generateJavaFromSchema(type:JavaExec) {
        main = 'org.apache.avro.tool.Main'
        args 'compile'
        args 'schema'
        args "${fileName}"
        args './src/main/java/'
        classpath = sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
    }
```

Then gradle expects something like "-PfileName=./src/main/resources/A.avsc",
otherwise gradle will complain fileName not defined

```
    ./gradlew generateJavaFromSchema -PfileName=./src/main/resources/A.avsc
```

Work around:set the value in *gradle.properties*

```
<pre>
fileName=./src/main/resources/A.avsc
</pre>
```

Then the following works , but it will use the default value gradle.properties file in the following case

```
    ./gradlew generateJavaFromSchema
```

You can still override if need be in the command line

```
    ./gradlew generateJavaFromSchema -PfileName=./src/main/resources/B.avsc
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This might not be directly helpful for the exact question, but in case you are for e.g. running gradle or gradle wrapper tasks directly from the terminal of IntelliJ IDEA, you can set the needed variable before running a gradle task directly in the terminal. The variable will be in memory for as long as the same terminal is still open.

So if you need to set a environment variable that will then be used in your gradle build somewhere, you can do it like this directly in the terminal:

```
set VAR_NAME=var_value
gradle clean build
```

after the VAR_NAME variable is set, the build (or any other gradle task you run in the same terminal) will use the value you set into the VAR_NAME variable (given the task uses it somewhere)