# How do I set an environment variable in Android Studio before it runs my gradle build

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My Gradle build looks at an environment variable called BUILD_NUMBER to determine the version to allocate to my android application as follows:

```
def buildNumber = System.getenv("BUILD_NUMBER") ?: "local"
```

So as long as that environment variable is set, the build number is used in defaultConfig as follows:

```
versionName "1.4.0."+buildNumber
```

Usually, Jenkins will call this Gradle build and supply the BUILD_NUMBER environment variable.

If I run the Gradle build from my command prompt, I know I can set BUILD_NUMBER = x.

However, if I build using Android Studio, how can I set the BUILD_NUMBER environment variable through Android Studio itself?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22605947/how-do-set-environment-variable-in-gradle-via-task

Comment: Thanks, but Iv read that post and a few others like it, unfortunately each developer needs to be able to set their own local environment build number (it changes whenever their is an official build on our CI server), so I don't want the build number coded into the build file itself.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I ended up using the following in my build.gradle:

```
def buildNumber = System.getenv("BUILD_NUMBER")
if (buildNumber == null) {
    Properties properties = new Properties()
    properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
    buildNumber = properties.getProperty('buildNumber')?:"NoBuildNumberFound"
}
```

Because the local.properties file is not supposed to be committed to your source code repository, each developer manages their own copy.

So if they want to set the buildNumber on their local Android Studio, they simply add the following to their local.properties:

```
buildNumber=7
```

So on a local developers machine, the build number will be set to what ever they put into their local.properties file, but on our Jenkins server, it will use the environment variable BUILD_NUMBER

Our Jenkins server sets the BUILD_NUMBER environment variable

Answer (score 18):

One option is to make use of gradle properties that can be overriden by environment variables. You can read about it [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_properties_and_system_properties).

> If the environment variable name looks like **ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT**_*prop*=somevalue, then Gradle will set a prop property on your project object, with the value of somevalue.

What this means is that you can

1. set `BUILD_NUMBER=42` in your `.properties` file (project, or global) as you would usually do,
2. and in your CI you would name the environment variable `ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_BUILD_NUMBER`, overwriting or setting `BUILD_NUMBER` in your CI build.

---

*Note:* Use `gradle.properties` in your project root directory, and do not modify `local.properties`.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me come to my solution. Unfortunately the properties in the local.properties file is not automatically made available in build.gradle, so I had to manually read the local.properties file in my build.gradle script.

Comment: @dleerob Glad I could help. `local.properties` are generated and used by android studio / android plugin. The "local" properties are in the `gradle.properties` file in the project root dir. It's confusing :/

Comment: beautiful. Thanks for this smooth answer.

Answer (score 7):

These are just environment variables.

If under Windows, go to the OS control panel and type "environment" in the search box at the top right. Then click on "Edit environment variables for your account", highly user friendly and no admin rights required. Restart the Android Studio after the edit.

If under Linux, edit .bashrc in your home folder (`vi ~/.bashrc` or with some other editor). Environment variables can be set there. `source ~/.bashrc` (or logout/login) and restart the Android Studio after the edit.

Comment: This is correct and works. I do not understand what do you want here to say with this downvote.

Comment: I think I expect the var to be loaded from the android project itself (like in the gradlew file for exemple) so those who works with you have the env var and your system is not polluted by it.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way on React Native:

```
namespace "myapp.io"
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "myapp.io"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 39
    versionName "0.3.8"
    resValue "string", "build_config_package", "myapp.io"
    manifestPlaceholders = [APPSFLYER_HOST: project.env.get("APPSFLYER_HOST"), APPSFLYER_PREFIX: project.env.get("APPSFLYER_PREFIX")]
}
```

Then in my AndroidManifest:

```
<data android:scheme="https"
            android:host="${APPSFLYER_HOST}"
            android:pathPrefix="${APPSFLYER_PREFIX}" />
```