# How to use gradle to add directory to os environment path?

Tags: gradle, environment-variables

I'm using selenium to do automated testing, and I want to write a gradle script to setup local environment for selenium. I've setup a task to starting selenium-server before run tests. But I am confused when trying to add a directory which stores browser drivers to os environment path before starting selenium-server. Any helps, thx.

**[Edited]**:
I know there are alreadly [similar questions that have been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22605947/), but I wonder whether there are an elegant way to add dir to path in both windows and linux with gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just provide an optional solution:

```
import org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem;
task runSelenium(type: Exec) {
    String path = System.getenv('PATH')

    doFirst{
       String webdriverDir = "$projectDir/webdriver"
       if(OperatingSystem.current().isWindows()){
           path = path + ";" + webdriverDir
       }

       if(OperatingSystem.current().isLinux()){
           path = path + ":" + webdriverDir
       }

       environment 'PATH', path 
       commandLine 'java', '-jar', 'webdriver/selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar'
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of juggling with the question of the operating system, just use System.getProperty("path.separator") directly.