# Gradle Environment variables. Load from file

Tags: bash, gradle, environment-variables

I am new to Gradle.

Currently I have this task:

```
task fooTask {
    doLast {
        exec {
            environment 'FOO_KEY', '1234567' // Load from file here!
            commandLine 'fooScript.sh'
        }
    }
}
```

**fooScript.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $FOO_KEY
```

Everything works great. But I have `env.file` with all needed environment variables. This file is used in Docker builder.

**env.file**

```
FOO_KEY=1234567
```

---

Question: how can I use `env.file` together with Gradle `environment` to load all needed env. params?

Comment: Doing this in `bash` would surely be a hack, I'm sure `gradle` has a way to do this more neatly

Comment: to read a file `String fileContents = new File('/path/to/file').text` then you will need to parse the content.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What about this :

```
task fooTask {
    doLast {
        exec {
            file('env.file').readLines().each() {
                def (key, value) = it.tokenize('=')
                environment key, value
            }
            commandLine 'fooScript.sh'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

I give also my version (check if line is not empty and not a comment, also donot override env var):

```
file('.env').readLines().each() {
        if (!it.isEmpty() && !it.startsWith("#")) {
            def pos = it.indexOf("=")
            def key = it.substring(0, pos)
            def value = it.substring(pos + 1)

            if (System.getenv(key) == null) {
                environment key, value
            }
    }
}
```

But actually, I think they should add this feature as a exec plugin property! It's quite common now to use `.env` file.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is the only one i've been able to produce and which satisfies two of the most importants requirements to provide an efficient "UNIX standard environment file import" in Android studio :

- Loads a file which depends of the Build Type (at least : debug and release)
- Exposes specified environment variables in the Android code, actually not as environment variables but as buildConfigFields content.

```
ext {
    node_env = ""
}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.name == "debug") {
        project.ext.set("node_env", "development")
    } else if (variant.name == "release") {
        project.ext.set("node_env", "production")
    }

    file("." + node_env + '.env').readLines().each() {
        if (!it.isEmpty() && !it.startsWith("#")) {
            def pos = it.indexOf("=")
            def key = it.substring(0, pos)
            def value = it.substring(pos + 1)

            if (System.getProperty(key) == null) {
                System.setProperty("env.$key", value)
            }
        }
    }

    if (variant.name == "release") {
        android.signingConfigs.release.storeFile file(System.getProperty("env.ANDROID_APP_SIGNING_STOREFILE"))
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias System.getProperty("env.ANDROID_APP_SIGNING_KEYALIAS")
        android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword System.getProperty("env.ANDROID_APP_SIGNING_STOREPASSWORD")
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword System.getProperty("env.ANDROID_APP_SIGNING_KEYPASSWORD")
    }
    android.defaultConfig.buildConfigField "String", "ANDROID_APP_URL", "\"${System.getProperty("env.ANDROID_APP_URL")}\""
}
```

Kotlin :

```
Log.i(TAG, BuildConfig.ANDROID_APP_URL)
```

Please let me know what you think of it as i'm not completly sure how it works, especially to select the good file to load.

Answer (score 1):

There are plugins to load env vars from a .env file (e.g. this [one](https://github.com/uzzu/dotenv-gradle))

So a sample build file will look something like this (Kotlin DSL)

```
plugins {
    id("co.uzzu.dotenv.gradle") version "1.1.0"
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    //will pass the env vars loaded by the plugin to the environment of the tests
    environment = env.allVariables
}
```

Comment: This throws an erorr, shouldn't it be `tasks.withType(Test)`?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Spring Boot `bootRun` task or anything that has a runner

```
tasks.named('bootRun') {
    doFirst {
        file('.env').readLines().each() {
            def (key, value) = it.tokenize('=')
            environment key, value
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up doing it in my gradlew file. A possible drawback is that the change tends to be overwritten on upgrades to gradle.

```
# Hack: export all variables in the .env file
#
ENV_FILE=../../.env
if [ ! -f $ENV_FILE ];then
    echo "WARNING/DEV ENV Missing a ${ENV_FILE} file with environment variables (secrets)";
fi
for secret in `cat $ENV_FILE`;do export $secret;done
```

Answer (score 0):

For those folks who are using `build.gradle.kts`

```
fun getMyVersion() : String {
    return file(".env.file")
        .readLines()
        .map { item -> item.split("=") }
        .single { (k, v) -> k == "APP_VERSION" }
        .get(index = 1)
}

my_version = getMyVersion()
```